# Send Scheduled Reminders fails

Tags: scheduled-reminders, scheduled-job

### Installation Details

- WordPress 4.7.3
- CiviCRM 4.7.17
- CiviVolunteer 4.6-2.2.1
- Angular Profiles 4.6-1.0.2
- SparkPost 1.1 (verified working)

### Problem Description

I have a CiviEvent set up with a schedule reminder. The variables in the email template are:

- {event.title}
- {contact.display_name}
- {event.title}
- {event.start_date}
- {event.summary}
- {event.description}
- {event.info_url}

When the cron job runs, the email is not sent and I get this error in the scheduled jobs log and no emails are sent:

> Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
> a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
>
> Full message:
> Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Failure, >Error message: Cannot build query. Variable "@selectedValues" is unknown.

Any idea what is wrong and how to debug and fix it?

Comment: Updated to WP 4.7.4 and CiviCRM 4.7.18... no change. Same error.

Comment: CiviCRM 4.7.19 and the problem persists.

Comment: CiviCRM 4.7.22... stiiiiill broken

Oh, and I have removed CiviVolunteer and AngularProfiles extensions, and SparkPost is disabled.

Comment: Would {event.summary} happen to be an HTML table?  Could it be the same type of issue as https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/58?

Comment: Can confirm I'm *still* getting this (huge) problem in CiviCRM 5.4 - and It does seem that smarty is the problem. Not sure on the solution, though I think maybe if the older failed emails can be cleared out, it should run properly again with ones not using **event.description**